# Access Ui Control from an other thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

so I want to access a label in my main form from a static Method in another class within another thread

How do I do that?

by the way, I used this code to start Threads

```
 new Thread(new ThreadStart(WebHelper.Check)).Start();
```

Comment: You shouldn't.  Move data around, not controls.

Answer (score 2):

The UI can only be altered by the UI Thread. If your thread is in the same class as the form, you could access the UI Thread by using the [Control.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netcore-3.1) method.

```cs
this.Invoke(new Action(() => {
    //UI Code here
}));
```

However, if you want to access it from another class, I would recommend using [events](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-event) to access the UI's class, and then you can use Invoke.

```cs
//This would be in your class
public delegate void UIStuff(string text);
class AClass
{
    public static event UIStuff ChangeLabel;

    public static void StaticFunction() {
         ChangeLabel.Invoke("Test");
    }
}
```

```cs
//This would be your form class
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1(){
        AClass.ChangeLabel += AClass_ChangeLabel; //Note you can press tab for auto complete
    }
    AClass_ChangeLabel(string text) {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => {
            this.MainLabel = text;
        }));
    }
}
```

Note: I believe you could also change the label by creating a new instance in your static method `Form1 f1 = new Form1();`, but I don't believe this is what you want.

Comment: Please put the salient details from the linked page directly in your answer. Links as content for questions are actively discouraged.

Comment: I'm following your answer and will be happy to up-vote if you can improve it.